# Populate tableview with pickerview

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uipickerview

I have a button, a pickerview and a tableview. When I push the button, the current selection of pickerview will be filled in the table view.  Here is the code of button which pick value from pickerview

```
- (IBAction)addCourse:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSInteger numRow=[picker selectedRowInComponent:kNumComponent];//0=1st,1=2nd,etc
    NSInteger SeaRow=[picker selectedRowInComponent:kSeaComponent];//0=fall,1=spring,2=summer
    NSInteger CourseRow=[picker selectedRowInComponent:kCourseComponent];

    NSString *num=Number[numRow];
    NSString *season=Season[SeaRow];
    NSString *course=Course[CourseRow];

    NSString *msgCourse=[[NSString alloc ]initWithFormat:@"%@ ",course];
    NSString *msgSeason=[[NSString alloc ]initWithFormat:@"%@ ",season];
    NSString *msgYear=[[NSString alloc ]initWithFormat:@"%@ ",num];

}
```

Then I want to populate msgCourse,etc to my tableview

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 ...Content from above msgCourse and etc

    return cell;

}
```

How to fix the gap in my second part please? Or any example to look at please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following code to decide whether or not that fits into your requirements based on what I understand from your question. If it does not, please leave a comment then I will try my best to follow up.

**First Step:** if you have not done the delegation via storyboard, here is the first thing that you should do programatically:

```
  -(void)ViewDidLoad
  {  
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.datasource = self;
   }
```

**Second Step:** I have not seen a mutablearray in your code, but I assume that you are going to make msgCourse to NSMutableArray.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// I assume you have only one section
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
 return [self.msgCourse  count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if(!cell){
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        }

    cell.textLabel.text=[self.msgCourse objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

**Last Step:** By the way, do not forget to add the following line of code into your button action to reload your tableView, I assume you update the NSMutableArray and would like to refresh the tableView.

```
- (IBAction)addCourse:(UIButton *)sender {
   .....
   .....
   .....
   [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Here is the good tutorial, it is worth to duplicate for the sake of learning: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It report error on cell.textLabel.text = msgCourse;  I think msgCourse is a local variable? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. If I need to populate more than one messages in multiple lines of tableview, do I need to fix something please?

Comment: my code has been updated see above. But you should make it NSMutableArray

Comment: You are welcome, I have also added a tutorial in my answer. It is good to follow.

Comment: Thanks, already studying on it. Last question, in your code msgCourse should be global, right? because the row of tableview is determined by it .